# Biplot of principal components

Tags: r, ggplot2

#### Problem

I'm having trouble plotting with ggplot the principal components as vectors projected on the plane given by two of the original variables in my dataset, together with the observations. As far as I can tell, the problem does not depend on the dataset, I've tried this with a few, but `df` below is the [Body Measurements Dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/saurabhshahane/body-measurements-dataset) in Kaggle, excluding the first two columns.

#### Code

I have a working script for the reciprocal problem: plotting the original variables in the plane given by the first two principal components, replicating in ggplot the output of `biplot()`. I do the singular value decomposition manually. The code for this is the following.

```
x <- df %>% as.matrix() %>% scale()
matrices <- svd(x)
# get the coords of the obvs wrt the PCs
df.pc <- matrices$u %*% diag(matrices$d) %>% as.data.frame()
df.pc$Labels <- rownames(df)

# get the coords of the original variables wrt to the PCs
old.basis <- sqrt(diag(matrices$d)) %*% matrices$v %>% as.data.frame()
old.basis$Names <- names(df)

ggplot(df.pc, aes(x = V1, y =V2, label= Names)) +
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1) +
  geom_text() + 
  geom_segment(data = old.basis, aes(x = 0, y = 0, xend = V1, yend = V2),
               arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.1, 'inches')), color = 'orange') +
  geom_text(data = old.basis, aes(label = Names), color = 'orange')
```

This works like a charm. I tried the same approach to produce the plot I previously said.

```
# get the coords of the PCs wrt to the original variables
new.basis <- t(sqrt(diag(matrices$d)) %*% matrices$v) %>% as.data.frame()
names(new.basis) <- names(df)
new.basis$Names <- names(old.basis[,1:11]) # last column is Names

ggplot(df, aes(x = Y1, y = Y2, label = row.names(df)) ) +
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1) +
  geom_text() + 
  geom_segment(data = new.basis, aes(x = 0, y = 0, xend = Y1, yend = Y2),
               arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.1, 'inches')), color = 'orange') +
  geom_text(data = new.basis, aes(label = Names), color = 'orange')
```

here `Y1` and `Y2` are the names I gave to the first two variables in `df`. But...

#### The error I get

...I get the following error every time.

```
Error in `check_aesthetics()`:
! Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (11): label
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Comment: The error message clearly points to an inconsistency in your input data. You've given us the code, but not the data.  It's going to be hard to help you.

Comment: @Limey I editted the question to include the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for :

[image]

Code:

```
ggplot(df.pc, aes(x = V1, y = V2)) +
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1)+
  geom_point() +
  geom_segment(data = new.basis, aes(x = 0, y = 0, xend = HeadCircumference, yend = ShoulderWidth),
               arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.1, 'inches')), color = 'orange')+
  geom_text(data = new.basis, aes(x = HeadCircumference, y = ShoulderWidth, label = Names), color = 'orange')
```

You might check your last ggplot code as it seems to contain typo/inconsistency (`df` instead of `df.pc`, `Y1` & `Y2` for `V1` & `V2`, ...)

Comment: No, that's not it, sorry. See `df.pc` contains the coordinates of the observations wrt the principal components, and I wish to plot the observations wrt to the original variables, that's why i have to use `df`. And `Y1`, `Y2` are placeholders for the names of the original variables, my bad, at first I wanted to write the code very generally.